# Cors Issue in Angular and IBM webseal configuration

Tags: angular, cors, webseal

My angular application is configured with webseal. So I use the webseal url to access my angular application in the browser .When I use the webseal url the browser automaticatlly redirects the url to my web server url and the portal loads.The problem is the same webseal domain API url is used in the application to make REST API calls and because of which I get CORS error in the browser. (ie) trying to access another domaim from a different domain. Please help on how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is on the webseal side, allow clients to access `OPTIONS` and `CORS` headers. Since you didn't give anything that can be reproduced or concrete I can't be of further help.

Comment: Thank you Mike. Is this the only option? Can webseal be configured without re direction . From Webseal perspective they consider allowing CORS as security issue.

Comment: I think it’s the only viable one because you need to enable access to your app which could be hosted on many domains. You could enable all CORS with `*`

Comment: Hi Mike , First of all os it possible to implement webseal on client side angular application? Because the Webseal url in the browser automatically redirects to webserver url. The webserver url is being exposed in the browser and the user can also directly hit the webserver url without webseal url.Looks like webseal is not meant for client side application.

Answer (score 0):

Add CORS blocker to your browser (ex:Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: * for Chrome). Sometimes this will not work for POST methods. Therefore you have to handle this issue from the backend.

Comment: Thank you Dulaj. Is this the only option? Can webseal be configured without re direction . From Webseal perspective they consider allowing CORS as security issue.